# laravel json result replace "/" with "\/"

Tags: php, json

Hi was wondering when I return JSON result using laravel 5 it replace every single `'/'` with `'\/'` which cause me a trouble as the url I return through the controller is no longer working

for example, in controller:

```
$url = 'icon/nature/animals/cat-2.png';
$result = array('data'=>$url);

return response()->json($result);
```

in jquery response it returns `'icons\\/nature\\/animals\\/cat-2.png'`

How can I avoid this to happen, thank you

Comment: it's a mistake or you are aware that it should be:
`$result = array('data' => $iklans);`
but maybe?:
`$result = array('data' => $url);`

Comment: @W92 no, my bad my code was $url

Comment: I don't know what library you use, but usual json_decode has special option to don't escape slashes - `echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: If the URL isn't valid then the JSON decoder is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `encodeURI` (build-in javascript function):

For example:

```
encodeURI('http:\/\/www.google.com') => 'http://www.google.com'

encodeURI('icons\/nature\/animals\/cat-2.png') => 'icons/nature/animals/cat-2.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `json()` method's blueprint:

```
public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0)
```

Use the `$options` parameter to set your desired escape options. To see a full list of JSON constants, check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

You are going to need the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` constant to achieve the behavior you need.